# <svg> not recognized by the server

Tags: reactjs, svg, dom, icons

I am driving crazy with this thing.

I am running a SPA in React, working fine on several hundreds of servers.

On a specific server of one of my customers (I mean: just one single server) there is a weird problem with svgs, let me explain.

The svg icons are in the DOM, but they don't show up. The svg tag is not even recognized by the browser DOM.

[svg not recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKR6g.png)

I found that, if I try to edit HTML via inspector by adding a space after  tag, the svg become magically appears.

[adding a space after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anXHD.png)

[...tadaaaa! magic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGTLO.png)

I am using [iconify](https://github.com/iconify/iconify) for React for rendering the svgs.

I tried also to run on the server this simple html file:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
<script>
    

    const svg = `<svg xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        xmlns:xlink="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        aria-hidden="true" 
        role="img" 
        class="iconify iconify--dashicons" 
        width="18px" 
        height="18px" 
        preserveaspectratio="xMidYMid meet" 
        viewbox="0 0 20 20" 
        style="color: rgb(0, 113, 174);"
    >
        <path fill="currentColor" d="M6 15V2h10v13H6zm-1 1h8v2H3V5h2v11z"></path>
    </svg>`;

    document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = svg;

</script>
</html>
```

And this works fine.

Anyone can undestand what's the problem on this server?

Thanks in advance

M

Comment: It's a bit hard to debug when you only have images... The namespace for SVG is not `https://www.w3.org/2000/svg` but `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`. Does that change anything?

Comment: The namespace is added by the iconify library. Anyway I'll try to change this, thanks :)

Comment: @chwahl I tried to change the namespace (manipulating the DOM with Chrome inspector) of svg but it doesn't work. It's the first time I see something like that :(